# Getting a download link of a file on one drive, without "content-disposition" in the headers?

Tags: onedrive

I have file in my onedrive. As I can see, it allows a sharing link, and embedding link. They can be converted to direct download link, by replacing the "resid" to "download". However still, it forces "download dialog box" instead of showing it into browser directly. Is their any way, I can remove the "content-disposition" from the download links i receive ?

In dropbox, it's possible by using dl=0.  But there doesnot seem to be any option for onedrive.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone.

You can call the meta data api.

```
GET /drive/items/{item-id}
GET /drive/root:/{item-path}
```

If the request is successful then you will get a response something like below. The `item-id` is your file id

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "id": "0123456789abc",
  "name": "example.xlsx",
  "eTag": "123918093j1lk2jlkda",
  "cTag": "k1ml4klkasljasidj1l2j34lkaslz",
  "createdBy": { "user": { "id": "1234", "displayName": "Ryan Gregg" } },
  "createdDateTime": "string (timestamp)",
  "lastModifiedBy": { "user": { "id": "1234", "displayName": "Ryan Gregg" } },
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "string (timestamp)",
  "size": 1234,
  "webUrl": "http://onedrive.com/...",
  "parentReference": { "driveId": "12345", "id": "root", "path": "/drive/root:" },
  "folder": { "childCount": 4 }
}
```

The response is actually truncated. But you can try this API and you will get all the details in the response. To download a file you will find a

```
@content.downloadUrl in the response.
```

[click here for more details](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/get.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch link for 'embed' rather than 'view', it will provide you a embed link. After Replacing '/embed?' with '/download.aspx?' in that url, this url will become direct download url and will not take you to microsoft webpage. I know this is hacky solution, however this is only solution I have. The above answer by SK is also correct to some extant, however, downloadUrl obtained from metadata expired very quickly. So you cannot put into a static html page.